# Export Woocomerce Image Product URL

Tags: woocommerce-offtopic, images, mysql, export, production

Hi I am try to export with mysql url image of woocommerce.

For export orders I using this method and that work perfect.

select * from wp_posts where post_type like 'shop%' into outfile '/var/lib/mysql-files/export-posts' CHARACTER SET utf8;

Now I need to know which column using woocommerce for product image.

Comment: Questions about third-party plugins are [off-topic](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic) here. You'll need to consult their documentation or use one of their official support routes for guidance on this.